# Angular App Running Slow on Android Web View / Chrome

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, android-webview, chromium, hybrid-mobile-app

I've an Ionic Hybrid Application which internally using Web view to Run the Application(This is an Angular Application which using Angular Version 14). This app running very slow after January 23, 2024.
There is not any major changes in the application which can cause this slowness.

When I tried with Android System Web View update uninstall this is working fine, but not on latest Android web view. This seems to some issue with chromium update. Don't know what has been updated in recent release.

Comment: are you sure that all the tags that you added is relevant to the question ?